# Is Netflix-Desktop down for everyone?

Tags: firefox, wine, netflix

Netflix-Desktop isn't working currently. Every time I select a movie to play I get asked if I would like to install silverlight. I believe Firefox updated itself but am not sure. I did

> apt-get remove netflix-desktop --purge
>   and then
>   apt-get install netflix-desktop

It still asks if I would like to install Silverlight to watch my movie when I click on it.

Comment: Thanks. Should've used better wording than "Netflix-desktop won't work" when searching Google for this problem :(